# How to change the hidden property of labels in coreplot?

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

with reference to the link : http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/fee73a040defce9b?pli=1&fb_source=message

The user talks about setting the labels hidden property in xcode. He sets to NO in one case and YES for another. I wonder how to make this change? Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

That post is 10 months old. Core Plot has changed quite a bit in that time. I'm sure whatever bug was causing that issue has been fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=363 Hello Eric  This was your reference in another post! Just change the collapselayers = YES from NO. It works.